# Cannot display wordpress thumbnail

Tags: plugins, uploads, thumbnails

I wrote a simple Wordpress Plugin that upload all images inside a folder located on another server. The uploading process is working well, but for some reason when I go inside `Library` I have a blank thumbnail:

[image]

when I add the file using my own plugin, I also create the post inside the `wp_posts` table, in this case contains the following info:

[image]

and inside the `wp_postmeta` table I have the following:

[image]

is there any reason why the thumbnail isn't showing up?
Kind regards.

Comment: Do you also use `wp_generate_attachment_metadata()` to generate the thumbnails for the uploaded media?

Comment: Are you sure you've properly set the upload directory? That's usually the issue in these cases. But also make sure you're using `wp_generate_attachment_metadata()` otherwise the thumbnail won't be created, file size isn't calculated and so on.

Comment: @JackJohansson  I didn't called that method, but the problem is another now: this plugin isn't installed on wordpress but it's an API which runs on another server, so how can I call the method required by wordpress from an external code?